# Python pandas dataframe add element to previous row values and create a new column

Tags: python, pandas, cumulative-sum

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dzigm.png)

```
Volume = [-1 -2 0 1 3 -1 -2 -1 -2 2 -2 -1 0]

Net_rate = [1 0 0 1 0 1 2 3 0 0 1 0]
```

I have the Pandas dataframe 'Volume' and need to create the column 'Net_rate'.

The algorithmic calculation is like that:

if Volume[i]*Volume[i-1]>0 
then Net_rate[i-1]+1 
else 0

I tried the following code but returns error:

```
def f_DataSlider(df, input, n, name):
    """Calculate the moving average for the given data.

    :param df: pandas.DataFrame
    :param n: 
    :return: pandas.DataFrame
    """
    Slider = pd.Series(df[input].shift(n), name=str(name))
    df = df.join(Slider)
    return df

data = f_DataSlider(data, 'Volume', 1, 'Volume_1')

mask2 = (data['Volume']*dfohlc['Volume_1'])>0
dfohlc.loc[mask2, 'Net_rate'] = dfohlc['Net_rate'].shift(-1)+1
dfohlc.loc[~mask2, 'Net_rate'] = 1
```

How should I code it?
Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using `numba`

You can make use of `numba` here, just make sure to `pip install numba` first.  This option is slower than the `cumsum` option, but it helps to demonstrate how an algorithm for this problem would look.

***Setup***

```
from numba import njit
```

---

Create a boolean series using `shift`:

```
s = df.Volume.mul(df.Volume.shift(-1)).gt(0).tolist()

@njit
def increment(s):
    rate = [int(s[0]>0)]
    for idx, el in enumerate(s[1:]):
        if el:
            rate.append(rate[idx]+1)
        else:
            rate.append(0)
    return rate

increment(s)
```

```
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

#### Using `cumsum` and `groupby`:

```
s = df.Volume.mul(df.Volume.shift(-1)).gt(0).astype(int)

s.groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()).cumsum()
```

```
0     1
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     0
5     1
6     2
7     3
8     0
9     0
10    1
11    0
12    0
Name: Volume, dtype: int32
```

***Explanation***

We can use `shift` for the `Volume[i] * Volume[i-1]` check:

```
df.Volume.mul(df.Volume.shift(-1))
```

```
0     2.0
1    -0.0
2     0.0
3     3.0
4    -3.0
5     2.0
6     2.0
7     2.0
8    -4.0
9    -4.0
10    2.0
11   -0.0
12    NaN
Name: Volume, dtype: float64
```

We can take this series, and check it is greater than `0`:

```
df.Volume.mul(df.Volume.shift(-1)).gt(0).astype(int)
```

```
0     1
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     0
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     0
9     0
10    1
11    0
12    0
Name: Volume, dtype: int32
```

Now you can see the structure of the output is becoming clear, but we need to increment based on consecutive ranges of `1`, which we can do using a `groupby` trick to groupby consecutive values, and take the `cumsum`.

Comment: could you please explain the cumsum structure? I mean where is the multiplication check of the current*previous volume datum and where is the previous+1 if multiplication is greater than 0?

Comment: Added more explanation

Comment: Brilliant the cumsum way. I tried your approach and works amazingly! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer helped you out, please consider accepting it! Happy coding!